# Kivy - Can't change .text with id

Tags: python, class, oop, kivy, kivy-language

I am trying to change the text of a label using an id, I tried it with stringProperty, with objectProperty without any properties. There has to be something I am missing in my code because it simply does not work whatever I try and any help would be greatly appreciated.

This bit of code is a simple screen with 2 buttons, one for going to the other screen and one for changing the label

```
from kivy.app import *
from kivy.uix.button import *
from kivy.graphics import *
from kivy.uix.widget import *
from kivy.uix.label import *
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import *
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import *
from kivy.uix.relativelayout import *
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView
from kivy.properties import ListProperty, StringProperty,ObjectProperty
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager,Screen
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout

class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass

class Name(FloatLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Name, self).__init__(**kwargs)
    def changeName(self):
        print(self.ids)
        self.name = self.ids.nameOfSong.text
        print(self.name)
        self.ids.nameOfSong.text = 'name'
        self.name = self.ids.nameOfSong.text
        print(self.name)

class MainWindow(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.pos = (0, 0)
        self.size = (1,1)
        self.z = Name()
        self.add_widget(self.z)
    def swap(self):
        Name().changeName()
class SecondWindow(Screen,BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(SecondWindow, self).__init__(**kwargs)

class langApp(App):
    def build(self):
        sm = ScreenManager()
        sm.add_widget(MainWindow(name='main'))
        sm.add_widget(SecondWindow(name='second'))
        return sm

Builder.load_file("kiv.kv")
if __name__ == '__main__':
    langApp().run()
```

My kiv.kv file, most of it is not connected to the problem (I think)

```
#:kivy 1.11.1
WindowManager:
    MainWindow:
    SecondWindow:

<MainWindow>:
    name: "main"
    FloatLayout:
        pos: 0,0
        size: root.width,root.height
        Button:
            on_release:
                root.manager.transition.direction = 'left'
                app.root.current = "second"
            text: 'Stop'
            pos_hint: {'x':.45,'y':.1}
            size_hint: .1,.1
        Button:
            on_press: root.swap()
            text: 'Next'
            pos_hint: {'x':.65,'y':.1}
            size_hint: .1,.1

<SecondWindow>:
    name: "second"
    FloatLayout:
        pos: 0,0
        size: root.width,root.height
        Button:
            on_release:
                root.manager.transition.direction = 'right'
                app.root.current = "main"
            text: 'Stop'
            pos_hint: {'x':.45,'y':.1}
            size_hint: .1,.1

<Name>:
    Label:
        text: nameOfSong
        font_size: 20
        size_hint: None, None
        pos_hint: {'x': 0.435, 'y': 0.25}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few problems with your code:

First, your code as posted dos not run. The line in your `kv`:

```
text: nameOfSong
```

is illegal.

Second, the code:

```
def swap(self):
    Name().changeName()
```

is creating a new instance of `Name` and calling `changeName()` on that new instance. However, that new instance is not the one that is displayed in your GUI.

To fix that, you just need to call `changeName()` on the instance of `Name` that is in your GUI. Conveniently, you have saved a reference to the correct instance with the line:

```
self.z = Name()
```

So, you can change the `swap()` method to use that instance of `Name`:

```
def swap(self):
    self.z.changeName()
```

The other problem is that the `changeName()` method tries to use a non-existent id `nameOfSong`. To fix that (and to make your posted code runnable), just change the `<Name>` rule in your kv to define that `id`:

```
<Name>:
    Label:
        id: nameOfSong
        text: 'Some Name'
        font_size: 20
        size_hint: None, None
        pos_hint: {'x': 0.435, 'y': 0.25}
```

On an unrelated note, your code is building the `App` `GUI` twice. The line:

```
Builder.load_file("kiv.kv")
```

is building the `GUI` from the lines:

```
WindowManager:
    MainWindow:
    SecondWindow:
```

and your python code is building it again here:

```
def build(self):
    sm = ScreenManager()
    sm.add_widget(MainWindow(name='main'))
    sm.add_widget(SecondWindow(name='second'))
    return sm
```

You can delete those three lines from your `kv` file.